# Unable to integrate "Black Berry Dynamics" in React-Native (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, blackberry, xcode12, blackberry-dynamics

I followed these steps to integrate  :-

https://github.com/blackberry/BlackBerry-Dynamics-React-Native-SDK/blob/master/modules/BlackBerry-Dynamics-for-React-Native-Base/README.md#blackberry-dynamics-sdk-for-ios

and then in package.json ->

```
dependency {   
 "BlackBerry-Dynamics-for-React-Native-Base": "file:../../node_modules/BlackBerry-Dynamics-React-Native-SDK/modules/BlackBerry-Dynamics-for-React-Native-Base"
}
```

While building the react-native iOS app I am getting this issue :-

```
error Could not find the following native modules: BbdRNBase. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?
```

Once I moved to my iOS folder and run pod install I am facing issue like :-

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `BlackBerryDynamics` depended upon by `BbdRNBase`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

My react-version is 0.64
Xcode version is :- 12.1

Comment: your syntax used in declaring the dependencies under `package.json` seems to be incorrect. can you check to see if your `npm install` or `yarn install` is running properly?

Comment: Hi @kenmistry, thanks 
it installed blackberry in the app, and also got new issue with this,
issue :- 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate property not set. Either call [GDiOS authorize:] and pass an object that implements the GDiOSDelegate protocol, or set the delegate property of the GDiOS instance prior to calling [GDiOS authorize].

Comment: do you mean that the error described in this question has been resolved? this new error with GDiOS can perhaps be due to a pod framework not embed properly. have you check through the `Copy` steps under [this](https://github.com/blackberry/BlackBerry-Dynamics-React-Native-SDK/blob/master/modules/BlackBerry-Dynamics-for-React-Native-Base/README.md#blackberry-dynamics-sdk-for-ios)?

Comment: Yes , Did it again but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the following steps?

$ cd ios $ pod install $ cd .. $ react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

Answering in hope that it may helps someone,

This may be the issue of installation of the blackberry in the react-native project,

Step 1

```
Run command :- npm install ********path to the blackberry reactnative base folder********
```

Step 2

```
Check if package.json have blackberry now like this :- 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
*note* path may be different , it depends from where you installed it.
```

Step 3:-

```
Check if pod file have now black berry like this
pod 'BlackBerryDynamics', :path => '../node_modules/BlackBerry-Dynamics-for-React-Native-Base/ios/BlackBerryDynamics'

if not please add it manually.
```

That's it

Now it's time to run cd ios && pod install .